# People at 60 or over

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to write this:

> People at 60 or over are recommended not to work in stressful environment.

By ‘60 or over’ I mean those who are 60 years old and 60+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ***recommend*** things and you ***advise*** people.

So, in addition to dropping the **at**, I suggest a couple of different phrasings:

> People **60 and over** are ***advised to not*** work in **a** stressful environment.
>   ***It is recommended that*** people **60 and over** not work in stressful **environments**.

(You can use the plural *environments* or put an indefinite article in front of the singular *environment*.)

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to write it is just

> People 60 or over...

No need for "at".  This is because we normally express age by saying "She is 60", not "She is *at* 60".  [It is also somewhat more common to say "60 or **older**" rather than "60 or over".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=people%2065%20or%20*&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cpeople%2065%20or%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpeople%2065%20or%20older%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpeople%2065%20or%20over%3B%2Cc0)

Some examples:

> [Retired people 65 or older should especially beware using the short form...](https://books.google.com/books?id=tlssAQAAMAAJ&q=%22people%2065%20or%20older%20should%22&dq=%22people%2065%20or%20older%20should%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-7Kf6hsrdAhWopFkKHXa8AwkQ6AEIJzAA)
>
> [In Europe, the percentage of people 60 or over is expected to increase...](https://books.google.com/books?id=pAxQN_-ivL8C&pg=PA28&dq=%22people%2060%20or%20over%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimpLbWhcrdAhUNqlkKHY4BDlgQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22people%2060%20or%20over%22&f=false)
>
> [Here's a quick rundown of tax-deduction breaks for people 65 or over...](https://books.google.com/books?id=CaBIAAAAYAAJ&q=%22people%2065%20or%20over%22&dq=%22people%2065%20or%20over%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYvuOHhsrdAhULrVkKHUB2B5YQ6AEIPDAE)

Comment: I've also commonly heard it spelled out as [*People who are 60 or older...*](https://carolinapublicpress.org/3572/operation-fan-heat-relief-summer-fan-distribution/), also [*People aged 60 and **over**...*](https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/national-indicator-library/emergency-hospital-admissions-for-hip-fracture-in-people-aged-60-and-over), etc. The *aged* version also scores higher on Google Books Ngram Viewer.